# Active record of not in

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-2

```
 $this->db->query('DELETE FROM default_model WHERE cat_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM default_category)');
```

the active record format for this query

```
$query = $this->db->select('id')
                              ->get('category')->result();

                $this->db->where_not_in('cat_id',$query )
                        ->delete('model');
```

I tried a lot but could not do it. How to pass $query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query results are returned as standard objects. Therefore you need to fetch the ids from the returned objects in a non associative array before passing that array to the delete query.

Like this:

```
$result = $this->db->select('id')->get('category')->result();
$ids = [];
foreach($result as $result)
     $ids[] = $result->id;

$this->db->where_not_in('cat_id', $ids)->delete('model');
```

Comment: itse  working fine in my localhost. But when i upload it to online, it says unexpected parse error [ . what is wrong?

Comment: That is because the server you uploaded your code to has a very old version on PHP. The short array syntax was introduced in php 5.4. To get this working on you server switch to $ids = array(); on line 2.